# Vertical scrollable slider Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, slider

I have vertical slider. I need  to implement scroll part, when slider section is in view and scroll down slide 1 change to slide 2, scroll down slide 2 change to 3,

Like in this website: https://mercdev.com/what-we-do/mobile